# React native fetch throw exception Network request fail on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using fetch for API call and getting JSON response.
but it throws an exception on android but working on iOS.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: requestMethod,
    body: formData,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log("Response JSON :- " + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Exception :- " + error);
})
```

> Error:-
>
> "TypeError: Network request failed.
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:24140:18).
>
> ```
> at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:28784:27).
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:28537:20).
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:28364:16).
>
> at blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:28474:47.
>
> at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:3280:37).
>
> at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:2577:44).
>
> at blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:2334:17.
>
> at MessageQueue.__guard (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:2531:13).
>
> at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/1a80ef13-8ce9-4c75-a477-e214c5fd3ff2:2333:14)".
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use IP address of server instead of localhost:8081 in url.

Comment: you dont need to add :8080 along with ip ,just use http://your device ip/path of service.

Comment: after removing "headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }," issue solved